# Video goes to the right, making it not visible in the mobile view. Any css fix please?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The video on [this blog](https://rothian.com/service-cpt/solution-design-services/) goes to the right side [(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRRCf.jpg) on a smaller mobile screen and is not visible anymore.

I tried different positioning methods using CSS, tried creating another container which does not seem possible for all the pages maybe because of some bug, and a bunch of other things.

I would really appreciate a fix if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try repositioning that video file with CSS @media by accessing that video's id or class. If you could share your code with us it would be easier to help. -Thanks

Comment: I tried it, the code is generated using elementor so it'll be better if you could instead try the inspector to play around

Comment: The CSS positioning does not work for me, anything in particular you think that would work ?

Comment: Try possition: absolute; for the video thing

Answer (score 0):

For the mobile view. You will have to switch to the mobile view of your page in the left bottom corner of Elementor and position the video where you want it to appear on your page without using additional css.

Comment: Can't reposition. Not sure why. Anything I could do in css?